# No update component react hooks context

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-context

The function **"AdicionaItem"** not reload the map of component **"Items.tsx"** why?

**<Itens.tsx>**

```
const { transacao } = useContext(TransacaoContext);
return (
   transacao.itens.map(({descricao}: TransacaoItens) => (<h1>{descricao}</h1>)
);
```

**<TransacaoContext.tsx>**

```
const [transacao, setTransacao] = useState<Transacao>(transacaoInicial);

function AdicionaItem(item: TransacaoItens) {
        let novosValores = transacao;
        novosValores.itens = [...novosValores.itens, item];
        setTransacao(novosValores);
    }
```

**<Consulta.tsx>**

```
const { AdicionaItem } = useContext(TransacaoContext);

function Adiciona(){
   AdicionaItem({descricao: "Teste"});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your useState hook is outside of your functional component. Try moving it inside of AdicionaItem:

```
function AdicionaItem(item: TransacaoItens) {
        const [transacao, setTransacao] = useState<Transacao>(transacaoInicial);
        let novosValores = transacao;
        novosValores.itens = [...novosValores.itens, item];
        setTransacao(novosValores);
    }
```

Comment: Hyetigran, the "const transacao" is used is others functions, ex: "RemoveItem"

Comment: In that case, you'll need to pass transacao and setTransacao as props for AdicionaItem. Then move your use state to a parent component, which looks like `Adiciona`. You will also need to pass the above state to all child components. This is called lifting state up, since several sibling components rely on it.